# I try to convert an RGB tiff orthophoto map to Grayscale and get ERROR

Tags: python, rgb, grayscale

I try to conver the RGB tiff with weights for the three bands like this:

```
    import gdal  
    import numpy as np
    
    rgbimg = gdal.Open('Panchro_image/OrthoPhotoMap_Repj.tif')
    
    band1 = rgbimg.GetRasterBand(1)  
    band2 = rbgimg.GetRasterBand(2)  
    band3 = rgbimg.GetRasterBand(3)
    
    ra = np.array(band1)  
    ga = np.array(band2)  
    ba = np.array(band3)  
   
    gray = ((0.2126*ra) + (0.7152*ga) + (0.0722*ba))
```

And i get this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Band'
I am new to python so i need some help :)
thanks anyway!

Comment: mb try to use opencv... it is easier to do it there

Comment: Thanks! I did it with opencv. It was easier! I wander if i can change the weights of the RGB convertion.

Comment: Do you know if i can save the tiff file without the LZW compression? In the cv2.imwrite comand?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not pro in opencv and I didn't work with tiff files :)